What does 動 mean in the grammatical term 動詞?
As a Sino-Japanese term, likely coined by Japanese grammarians, the etymology of 動詞 seems straightforward at first: 動 means "move" and 詞 means "word". The problem is what does "move" mean here?
It seems intuitive that 動詞 can be interpreted as "movement-word." Movement implies action, which verbs tend to convey. But not all verbs truly describe action or movement. Furthermore, the historical evidence I've found does not show this to be the case.
One of the earliest uses of this term seem to be for translating Dutch grammatical terms. In the manuscript 蘭語九品集 "Compilation on the Nine Parts of Speech of the Dutch Language" by the grammarian Shizuki Tadao, putatively thought to have been passed down to his disciples sometime near the end of the 18th century (probably 1798), 動詞 was used to translate the Dutch term werkwoord, literally "workword". In this case, I guess 動 didn't imply "move" as in the verb 動【うご】く "to move", but as in the verb 働【はたら】く "to work". Hence 動詞 "move-word" might have been an alteration of 働詞 "work-word". 働詞 "work-word" was used by some authors (1, 2, 4) during the Meiji era. The Ministry of Education also used it, although I had to infer the actual pronunciation of 働詞 from later grammars, which seems to be explicitly ハタラキコトバ.
(As an aside, I'd love it if you can share scholarly insights on another question of mine, What could be the reason why the kokuji 働 exists?)
In Dutch grammar, the name werkwoord "workword" doesn't seem to have anything to do with verbs as something that conveys action, but with verbs as something that is dynamic, something that changes its forms, in other words, conjugates. Therefore, a verb is an conjugative word. The opposite of werkwoord "workword" is naamwoord "nameword", which refers to static, or non-conjugative words, such as nouns, pronouns and adjectives. This dichotomy of "dynamic-static" is reflected in the translations used by Shizuki, namely 動詞 "dynamic word > werkwoord" and 静詞 "static word > naamwoord".
The concept of a "word that works", or one that conjugates, or ハタラク詞, was explicitly analyzed by Suzuki Akira in his 1824 grammar, 言語四種論, although Suzuki was referring to both verbs and adjectives, both of which conjugate in Japanese. Verbs were named ハタラキコトバ by a couple of later grammars, such as Tsurumine Shigenobu's 語学新書 (1872) and Tanaka Yoshikado's 小学日本文典 (1874), and adjectives (which also conjugate) gained their own names. Ochiai Naobumi made a distinction between auxiliaries which are dynamic (conjugative), and particles which are static (non-conjugative), hence their respective names 動助辞 and 静助辞, which bolster my theory.
All the above evidence seems to suggest 動詞 simply means "conjugative word." The problem is the other translations by Shizuki, the very guy who probably coined the word and spelling 動詞. He translated werkend werkwoord "working workword > transitive verb" as 動他詞, and called intransitive verbs 自動詞, and verbs in the passive voice 被動詞 (1). In all these terms, the implication doesn't seem to be "dynamic" or "conjugative", but may actually be "move > act on/use". 動他詞 (not 他動詞 as we use it today) would then mean "word that acts on something else", where 他 "something else" is an object. 自動詞 would then be "word that acts by itself", and 被動詞 would be "word that is acted on." As you can see, substituting "act on" with "conjugate" would make no sense. Verbs always conjugate whether in Dutch or in Japanese, and associating conjugation with some kind of object ("word that acts on something else") or agent ("word that is acted on") makes no sense.
Of all the names of the parts of speech in Japanese, I find 動詞 to be the most opaque. With most other terms, the names were likely translated from Dutch, English, French, Latin, etc. grammatical terms (naamwoord > 名詞, voornaamwoord > 代名詞, bijwoord > 副詞, hulpwoord > 助詞, hulpwerkwoord > 助動詞), or based on semantic function (形容詞 "word that describes"), or based on grammatical function (接続詞 "word that joins", 連体詞 "word that joins with a substantive"). But with 動詞, none of these possibilities seems to be satisfactorily explanatory. Semantic function is clearly inadequate, given that not all verbs convey movement, and historical evidence doesn't prove it to be the primary explanation, if an explanation at all. As a translation, 動詞 seems to be from the Dutch werkwoord, but this also conflicts with its grammatical function as shown in terms like 動他詞, 自動詞 and 被動詞.
So what does 動 mean in 動詞? As a casual amateur researcher, I don't have access to all documents available, especially early manuscripts by Shizuki Tadao and grammarians before him during the late Edo period. All I got are scans that date a little too late, well into the Meji era. So if you have access to earlier grammars, be they Dutch or Japanese, I'd appreciate your insights.

This has me curious how grammarians before Western contact looked at the language and what terms they used

@Angelos Apparently the Japanese were already conscious of different kinds of words as far back as the Manyoshu (8th century) with the kanji 辞 for particles. During the late Kamakura period (14th century) 手爾波 teniha "particles" and 詞 "non-particles" were distinguished. Those classifications were before the Dutch came to Japan (early 17th century). Some hundred years after first contact, some native grammarians came up with their own terms, but most of the terms we use today can be traced back to Dutch-based translations. Source here.

Great research. I rather think you have answered most of your questions. One addition that you may already know: the concepts "conjugable words" and "non-conjugable words" also exist as 用言 and 体言 in the tradition of Japanese grammar. Here, 用 (also 活 or 活用) was originally read はたらき by Edo period scholars.

@broccoliforest Huh, I looked up 用言 and apparently it does date to the Edo period. I just assumed it was a Meiji invention. Clearly I still missed a lot in my research.

A neat coincidence that the pronunciation of 手爾波 includes 3/4 of テニヲハ, hmm?
